# Node-red how to identify a stream when listening on the same por

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, stream, buffer

I am using **Node-Red** to listen **TCP** on specific port (buffer), receive data from GPS trackers and save them to MySQL db.
This works fine for one device.

[image: node-red settings]

The thing is that, when multiple devices are sending data to the same IP/PORT how can I know that they are more then one device (devices are not sending IMEIs, serials, etc.).

**Is there any solution which shows me something like IP of incoming connection, connection id or idenitificator of session?**

Or I am missing something important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can now answer my own question.
I have found that we can use session id:

```
var session = msg._session.id;
```

If you know the session ID you can identify few different connections.